# Force ScrollView and/or RecyclerViewt to be always scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout

I couldn't find anything related.
My Activies contain a FAB, which adds entries to a RecyclerView. The RecyclerView is sometimes within a ScrollView.

However, the FAB often covers entries of the RecyclerView so it is not accessible.  If the RecyclerView has too few entries, it is impossible to get access to them completely.

My question is if there is a possibility to make a ScrollView/RecyclerView scrollable even with too few items? I already read about infinite Scroll, but this often cycles through the items, which is what I do not want.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYnO2.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need put a paddingBottom like examples below. Key point is  `android:clipToPadding="false"` part. By using this, when your content reach at the bottom, it will leave padding.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not always work.
In a plain Recyclerview, when I swipe down (to refresh), items disappear according to the padding.

When I want to scroll down the items reappear but i cannot scroll

Comment: @Raildex items cannot disappear because of padding, I use this method in my apps which are using by millions of people. After adding new items, padding will be moved to bottom of the list again, and your items will be visible. That's how it works. May be you are doing something wrong.

Comment: The Recyclerview has exactly the same attributes like you suggested tho.

Comment: @Raildex could you add your layout xml to your question. I think padding works but it stays behind bottom bar. Recyclerview must be over bottom bar or try to increase your paddingBottom value by +56 dp.

Comment: @Raildex fragment layout looks ok, but I need to see Activity layout, which includes this Fragment's container layout and BottomBar.